# Get the Real Type when passing an Interface Implementation into a generic Method<T>(T args) (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an EventAggregator Implementation that distinguishes between Event Types and calls all registered Callbacks with that Event Type as Parameter, so the Publish-Method looks like this:

```
public void Publish<T>(T args) where T : IEvent
{
     if (callbacks != null)
     {
          var callbacksByEvent = callbacks.GetCallbacksByEventType(typeof(T));
          if (callbacksByEvent != null)
          {
               foreach (var callback in callbacksByEvent)
               {
                   if (callback is Action<T>)
                   {
                        Task.Run(() => ((Action<T>)callback)(args));
                   }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

The IEvent is just an empty Marker Interface for the Event Classes. It works perfectly fine when passing a hardcoded Implementation like `SomethingHappenedEvent : IEvent` into the Method, but I wanted to create a Notification Window where any IEvent Implementation can be assigned to the Buttons "Yes", "No", "Cancel" and they will be executed when clicked:

```
private IEvent CancelEvent;

private void Cancel()
{
     if (CancelEvent != null)
     {
         EventAggregator.Publish(CancelEvent);
     }
}
```

In this Scenario, `callbacks.GetCallbacksByEventType(typeof(T))` returns NULL, because `T` is `IEvent`, but the Callback Methods are registered with the real Implementation:
`EventAggregator.Subscribe<SomethingHappenedEvent>(OnSomethingHappened)`

If I change it to `callbacks.GetCallbacksByEventType(args.GetType())`, I get the Callback List that I expect, but the if-statement

```
if(callback is Action<T>)
```

still returns false, because `T` is still `IEvent` and the Method is not an `Action<IEvent>`, but an `Action<SomethingHappenedEvent>`.

So the question is: how do I get the T to become my `SomethingHappenedEvent`?
I can get the actual Type from Class at Runtime using .GetType(), so it should be possible? I'm on .NET Framework 4.5.

I read a bunch of Stackoverflow Posts on Generics and Interfaces but couldn't quite find what I was looking for! Can you help please? Thank you for reading all of this :D

//Edit: Sorry, here's the code for the `GetCallbacksByEventType` Method:

```
        internal List<Delegate> GetCallbacksByEventType(Type eventType)
        {
            List<Delegate> callbacks;
            lock (delegateTable)
            {
                if (!delegateTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                List<WeakDelegate> weakReferences = delegateTable[eventType];

                callbacks = new List<Delegate>(weakReferences.Count);
                for (int i = weakReferences.Count - 1; i > -1; --i)
                {
                    WeakDelegate weakReference = weakReferences[i];
                    if (weakReference.IsAlive)
                    {
                        callbacks.Add(weakReference.GetDelegate());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        weakReferences.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }

                if (weakReferences.Count == 0)
                {
                    delegateTable.Remove(eventType);
                }
            }
            return callbacks;
        }
```

and the WeakReference Class is:

```
internal sealed class WeakDelegate
{
    readonly Type DelegateType;
    readonly MethodInfo DelegateFunction;
    readonly WeakReference DelegateTarget;


        public Delegate GetDelegate()
        {
            object target = DelegateTarget.Target;
            if (target != null)
            {
                return Delegate.CreateDelegate(DelegateType, target, DelegateFunction);
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the `callbacks.GetCallbacksByEventType` return? (actual signature) Or, what's the type of the callback in `foreach (var callback ...`?

Comment: Presumably callback of type Delegate or could be casted to Delegate. In which case I would suggest using DynamicInvoke. This is slightly slower than a cast and invoke but having used the event aggregator pattern in exactly this way the overhead is tiny compared to the other things that are going on the UI.

Comment: if `GetCallBacksByEvent(typeof(T))` contains logic to filter to only appropriate callbacks, why bother with the check at all?  To be honest, this looks like you're trying to engineer an overcomplicated solution...  As comment above says, post the code of the `callbacks` class... it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.  perhaps an abstract base class rather than an interface could be used here?

Comment: Mike ZBoray that did the trick! I knew the check for `if(callback is Action<T>)` was too much, I just didnt know another way to call the Delegate than casting it to `(Action<T>)` ! Thanks a lot :) I will read up on it ASAP! :)